# How to do parallel queries in postgis

Tags: postgis, parallel-processing

Is there any way to do queries in postgis using multiple cores in a transparent way, other than splitting my queries among several client connections ?

Comment: TThis question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network : dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: In PostgreSQL it's one query - one core. Why do you want more?

Comment: @JakubKania, I'm assuming there are vector operations in postgis queries which can be done in parallel. If so, is postgis prepared to do them in multicore cpu?

Comment: PostGIS is PostgreSQL extension and PG doesn't support parallelism yet (http://www.databasesoup.com/2013/05/postgresql-new-development-priorities-4_20.html). For normal applications that ain't really a problem since you'd want db to handle multiple queries concurrently then one really fast.

Comment: Mostly the answer is "no", we share the limitation of PgSQL. If you use a parallel cluster architecture on top of PgSQL, like PostgresXC or Stado, you can potentially get parallel execution of things like spatial joins.

Comment: 5 close votes with no reason as to why? I don't see anything in http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic that would make this question off-topic.  In fact, just the opposite.  I'm voting for the re-open because 1) similar questions already exist with up-voted answers on gis.stackexchange.com and 2) Jakub's comment would be an acceptable answer that would add value to the site for future PostGIS users or GIS users looking to select a database for parallel spatial queries.

Comment: You might use [pgpool](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) to execute a single query in parallel, across the PostgreSQL/PostGIS servers in your pool.

Comment: ["PostGIS users need parallism yesterday"](http://www.databasesoup.com/2013/05/postgresql-new-development-priorities-4_20.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick answer is that you can't do parallel queries. Not yet, at least.

**PostgreSQL**, the most common database engine that processes PostGIS queries, has [parallel query execution](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Parallel_Query_Execution) as a [development priority](http://www.databasesoup.com/2013/05/postgresql-new-development-priorities-4_20.html). Although there has been some progress on the prerequisite background worker API in versions 9.3 and 9.4, the timing of this feature is probably not expected for at least a year or more.

[**Postgres-XC**](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Postgres-XC), a related project, allows some queries to be executed in parallel on multiple nodes. PostGIS needs to be [built on each node using specific instructions](http://www.stormdb.com/content/enabling-postgis-postgres-xc?destination=node%2F934).

[**Stado**](https://www.stormdb.com/community/stado) is another clustering effort with massively parallel processing capabilities. It is designed to [work with PostGIS](http://foss4g-na.org/schedule2012/scaling-postgis-queries-with-stado/) ([slides](http://foss4g-na.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/ScalingPostGISWithStado.pdf)).

[**pgpool-II**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pgpool-II) is a middleware that offers parallel query, although I'm not sure if or how it can be configured for PostGIS.